# Construct an object using a static member function

Tags: c++

I have a static function that populates a passed by reference object and returns an integer to signal errors or success.

```
static int readDeformationGrid(const std::string& gridFile,
                                   DeformationGrid& defgrid)
```

Is it possible to use this same static member function to initialize the object? Is this a bad idea?

Something like

```
DeformationGrid(const std::string& gridFile)
{
    int ret = DeformationGrid::readDeformationGrid(gridFile, *this);
    if(ret < 0)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Error reading deformation grid file " + gridFile);
}
```

Or should I use a Factory pattern?

I think something like this is useful in reconfigurable objects, for example. A `reconfigure` method and the constructor would share the same code, so it would make sense to put it on a third member function, static since it might not have an object yet in the second case.

How do you call such a method on the constructor?

Comment: Out of interest, why can't you use a constructor?

Comment: Looks like you mean "initialize" when write "construct", am I right?

Comment: Why do you need the static member function at all? If you delete the default constructor and apply @Bathsheba's comment you can assume your objects are always in a consistent state.

Comment: Because I'd like to provide a static method that populates a pre-existing `DeformationGrid`. Althought you're right in my case I could just provide the constructor to do this.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 you are right.

Comment: i see no point in doing so. simply use ths ctor